# What is the best way to gather financial information from many different sources?

Tags: finance, yodlee

I've been tasked with creating an application for my company that will keep track of all of our client's investments and organize the historical data of same. Basically, I need to be able to search records by client, by ticker symbol, over a range of dates, etc.

The problem is that most of our clients have their investments though a bunch of different custodians, and thus the information is coming from a bunch of different sources. I've been looking though several APIs (Yodlee, Plaid, Buxter), but these all seem to be designed for use in making mass-market apps. This project is probably only going to be used by a handful of people within the company.

My question is: what's the best way to go about this, for someone with limited experience with APIs and REST? Should I try and find a way to extract info from each data source one at a time? Or should I just use an API? If the latter, which one?

Answer (score 0):

You are in the right place. We recommend you to use our latest Yodlee API-

https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API

https://developer.yodlee.com/apidocs/index.php#!/providerAccounts

Account addition flow- https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/API_Flow/Add_Account_With_ProviderAccount

which follows the rest standards and the API responses here are very simple, decluttered and will fulfill your requirements.

Hope this helps